# Upper bounds that obtain in a set

Tags: equation-solving

I have nearly 11^4 inequalities and I want to obtain the upper bounds of the solutions of the inequalities as given in a set. When use the command `Reduce`, i get the following intervals. This is only two ones.

`A<-0.756026||0.<A<1.94105`

`A<-0.757879||0.<A<7.36113`

I want to obtain the upper bounds of `A` as in the set. Namely, the output should be as
`{-0,756026,1,94105,-0.757879,7.36113}`

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
res = {A < -0.756026 || 0. < A < 1.94105,  A < -0.757879 || 0. < A < 7.36113};

res /. {Or -> List, Less -> (Last[{##}] &)} // Flatten
Sequence @@@ res[[All, All, -1]]
ArgMax[{A, #}, A] & /@ # & /@ res /. Or -> Sequence
```

all give

> {-0.756026, 1.94105, -0.757879, 7.36113}

Comment: It did not work in my computer

Comment: @MATIRMAK, some detail on how it didn't work would be useful.